# Localhost WCF service unavailable after stopping debug

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio

I have problem reaching my WCF service on localhost. When I start it from Visual Studio, everything is fine. However, as soon as I stop debugging it, the service is no longer available. This is odd, because it happens only with projects created by myself. When I download a solution (e.g. [this one](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/a-simple-duplex-service-in-wcf/)), everything is just fine and the service is available also after I stop debugging it.

Thus, I suppose, it is a configuration problem. However, I am not able to find it. Here is my Web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name ="svcbh">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name ="DuplexServer.CalculatorService" behaviorConfiguration ="svcbh" >
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http//localhost:3435/CalculatorService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint name ="duplexendpoint"
                  address =""
                  binding ="wsDualHttpBinding"
                  contract ="DuplexServer.ICalculatorDuplex"/>
        <endpoint name ="MetaDataTcpEndpoint"
                  address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using IIS Express, it's usually caused by Edit and Continue (Right click the project, select properties. It's a checkbox in the Web tab).

Disable this, and the service should keep running when you stop debugging.

On a related note, if you wish to simply start the service to have available (i.e. you don't want to debug, you just want it running), you can use "Start without Debugging" in the Debug menu (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> by default)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the settings for your solution/project is not what you desire. Go the properties of your WCF project and look at "Web" settings(plenty of information on the net about this)

You will probably need to change from "Use Visual Studio Development Server" to "Use local IIS Web Server"